# В чем принципиальная разница между обобщенными методами и обобщенными типами?

Tags: c#, generics, интерфейс, c#-faq

Столкнулся с непониманием.
Вот предположим, мне нужно создать интерфейс для какого то элемента бизнес логики, но я совершенно ничего не хочу знать о DTO между BLL и уровнем представления, для этого я напишу что то в таком духе:

```
public interface IOrderService<T> where T : class
{
    int MakeOrder(T t);
    T GetOrder(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetOrders();
    void Dispose();
}
```

тогда реализация на уровне BLL будет какая то такая:

```
class OrderService : IOrderService<OrderDTO>
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public OrderDTO GetOrder(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<OrderDTO> GetOrders()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int MakeOrder(OrderDTO t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Но почему я не могу сделать интерфейс таким:

```
public interface IResourceService
{
    int MakeResource<T>(T t);
    T GetResource<T>(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetResources<T>();
    void Dispose();
}
```

и реализовать его как то так:

```
class ResourceService : IResourceService
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public ResourceDTO GetResource<ResourceDTO>(int id)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public IEnumerable<ResourceDTO> GetResources<ResourceDTO>()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public int MakeResource<ResourceDTO>(ResourceDTO t)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Я понимаю, что речь идет о каком то непонимании базовых принципов. Поэтому прошу помочь разобраться.

Дополнение:

В общем вопрос свелся к тому, можно ли сделать как то так?

```
public interface IResourceService
{
    T GetResource<T>(int id);
}

public class ResourceService : IResourceService
{
    public T GetResource<T>(int id) where T : ResourceDTO
    {
        return new ResourceDTO();
    }
}
```

Если да, то как, если нет, то почему?

Comment: Мне не совсем понятна суть вопроса. Вы вполне может использовать 1 и 2 варианты, в зависимости от задачи. работать ли с определенным типом в классе или сохранить гибкость и оставить неопределенный тип, возможно различный для каждого метода

Comment: @morphey83 тут, скорее всего, суть вопроса в том, есть ли принципиальная разница между данными реализациями. Возможно, у них есть разные use-case.

Comment: На самом деле, я хочу понять, почему на этапе реализации интерфейса IOrderService<T> я могу явно указать тип, с которым будет работать реализация, а на этапе реализации IResourceService я не могу явно указать тип для его методов?

Comment: А использовать ограничение public T GetResource<T>(int id) where T : ResourceDTO я не могу, т.к. на этапе создания интерфейса я еще ничего не знаю о ResourceDTO

Comment: @АлександрКубит, _т.к. на этапе создания интерфейса я еще ничего не знаю о ResourceDTO_ подчините ResourceDTO интерфесу и используйте его в where

Comment: А в чем практическая польза искомого решения? Может вопрос стоит по-другому поставить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но почему я не могу сделать интерфейс таким:

Можешь, однако в этом случае `T` для каждой из функций

```
int MakeResource<T>(T t);
T GetResource<T>(int id);
IEnumerable<T> GetResources<T>();
```

будет своим и не зависеть от других, то есть можно будет вызвать `MakeResource` с одним `T`, `GetResource(id)` с другим `T`, `GetResource()` с третьим `T`

В случае же с

```
public interface IOrderService<T> where T : class
{
    int MakeOrder(T t);
    T GetOrder(int id);
    IEnumerable<T> GetOrders();
    void Dispose();
}
```

Тип `T` будет один и тот же у каждой из функций, тот что указан у класса.

---

> т.е. получается при реализации интерфейса IResourceService (ResourceService) я не смогу ограничить методы по типу

Да, ограничения на параметр типа должны совпадать с ограничениями типа в интерфейсе. То есть, если было `<T>`, то оно и останется, и указать параметр типа можно будет только при вызове.

Comment: Обобщенным методам можно тоже поставить одинаковое ограничение по типу, но тогда получится "копипаста", но работать они будут с одним типом.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение, но наверное я не правильно сформулировал вопрос, почему на этапе реализации интерфейса IOrderService<T> я могу явно указать тип, с которым будет работать реализация, а на этапе реализации IResourceService я не могу явно указать тип для его методов?

Comment: @АлександрКубит потому что обобщенные методы должны объявляться не с типом `ResourceDTO`, а с типом `T`, как написал автор ответа. Иначе какой смысл от этих обобщенных методов, если они получаются не обобщенными?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, я не понял про ограничение: в классе - generic параметр задается классом, и функции не могут его изменить, а в случае, когда у каждой функции свой generic параметр - его можно устанавливать каким угодно при каждом вызове

Comment: @АлександрКубит, почему не можешь? :-) можешь

Comment: Т.е. получается, реализуя интерфейс с обобщенными методами, я обязан реализовать его так, что бы методы остались обобщенными, а реализуя обобщенный интерфейс я могу оставить реализацию обобщенной, а могу сделать реализацию указав конкретный тип? Но тогда все таки какая то разница есть)

Comment: @АлександрКубит, я не совсем понял твое сообщение :-) Можешь добавить в вопрос небольшой пример о чем ты говоришь? или подробнее описать что ты имеешь ввиду :)

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: @Grundy теперь я понял вас.) Я имел ввиду немного другое. [В документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) сказано, что для отдельного метода можно задать свое ограничение по типу. Я имел ввиду, что если для класса его можно задать 1 раз, то для методов придется его задавать столько раз, сколько есть методов.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, ага, но при этом сам тип T может быть любым соответствующим этим ограничениям

Comment: @Grundy дада, я уже понял)

Comment: Я попробовал описать свой вопрос в дополнении, надеюсь, что получилось хотя бы более менее понятно, в любом случае спасибо, что пытаетесь помочь

Comment: @АлександрКубит, _Это ограничение языка или ограничение CLR?_ - точно не могу сказать, ошибку бросает компилятор, поэтому возможно дело в языке. Но в принципе логично, что под интерфейс должна подходить любая его реализация, а если ограничения будут сужать возможные классы, то уже не любая :)

Answer (score 0):

> В общем вопрос свелся к тому, можно ли сделать как то так?

```
public interface IResourceDTO
{
   ... 
}

public interface IResourceService
{
    T GetResource<T>(int id) where T : class, IResourceDTO, new();
}

public class ResourceService : IResourceService
{
    public T GetResource<T>(int id) where T : class, IResourceDTO, new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```